# Java Hibernate Annotation exception, referenceColumnNames not mapped to single property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to get list of Client Accounts for each Client Card, and then get Product Descriptions for each Client Account.

I am getting the following error using Java Hibernate:

```
            org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(ProductID) of query.dao.ProductDescription.productDescription referencing query.dao.ClientAccount not mapped to a single property
```

Please see the ClientCard, ClientAccount and ProductDescription.

ClientCard.java

```
@Table(name="ClientCard")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClientCard {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ClientID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int clientId;

    @Column(name = "ClientCardNumber", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String clientCardNumber;

    @Column(name = "MaskAccounts", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String maskAccounts;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn (name = "ClientID", referencedColumnName = "ClientID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<ClientAccount> clientAccounts;

}
```

ClientAccount.java

```
@Table(name="ClientAccount")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClientAccount {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClientAccountKey key;

    @Column(name="NickName", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String nickName;

    @Column(name="HideInSummary", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String hideInSummary;

    @Column(name = "MobileNickName", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String mobileNickName;

    @Column(name = "HideInMobile", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String hideInMobile;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ProductID", referencedColumnName = "ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<ProductDescription> productDescription;

}
```

ProductDescription.java

```
@Table(name="ProductDescription")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductDescription {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductDescriptionKey key;

    @Column(name = "Description", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String description;
}
```

ClientAccountKey.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class ClientAccountKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ClientID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int clientId;

    @Column(name="AccountID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String accountId;

    @Column(name="ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String productId;

    @Column(name="TransitID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String transitId;
}
```

ProductDescriptionKey.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class ProductDescriptionKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ProductID;

    @Column(name = "LanguageID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String languageID;

}
```

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: 1. For some better readability, get rid of the `@EmbeddedId` by placing all the values in the corresponding class and marking them with `@Id` 2. `@OneToMany` should be used like `@OneToMany(mappedBy="colName")`. For reference look on [this site](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) under point 4.

Answer (score 0):

Right now in your code:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "ProductID", referencedColumnName = "ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<ProductDescription> productDescription;
```

Since your `ProductDescription` table has composite key, you need to have two columns to join, so you should change it to:

```
 @OneToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "ProductDescription", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ProductID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "LanguageID") })
 private List<ProductDescription> productDescription;
```

Comment: The LanguageID column doesn't exist in ClientAccount so the code would return   `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: LanguageID in ClientAccount`

Comment: Whats the table name that has composite primary keys `ProductID` and `LanguageID` ?

Comment: Its ProductDescription. `ClientAccount Table (ClientID, AccountID, ProductID, TransitID, Nickname, ...). ProductDescription Table (ProductID, LanguageID, Description, ...)`

Comment: No, I'm asking there should be a join table for `ProductDescriptionKey` , where is that?

Comment: Alright, I have made an edit to the answer, please check.

Comment: I It didn't work. I tried a different approach by adding bi-directional map. So in my ClientAccount.java I have `@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<ProductDescription> productDescription;` and ProductDescription.java has `@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ClientAccount clientAccount;` but now I am getting `A Foreign key refering dao.ClientAccount from dao.ProductDescription has the wrong number of column. should be 4`